# How to implement end less pagination in Django

Tags: python, django, django-endless-pagination

I am trying to implement end less pagination in Django App but stuck at how to implement twitter like end less scrolling :

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class bookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Book admin class"""

    list_display = ('name','pub_date')

    ordering = ('name',)


admin.site.register(Book,bookAdmin)
```

My views.py :

```
from models import Book
from django.template import RequestContext 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


def latest_books(request,template = 'latest_books.html',
                  page_template = 'latest_books_page.html' ):

    context = {}    
    book_list = Book.objects.order_by('-pub_date')

    context.update( {'book_list': book_list, 'page_template': page_template,} )

    # override the template and use the 'page' style instead.
    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template

    return render_to_response(
        template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

My 'latest_books.html' template :

```
<html><head><title>Books</title></head>

<body>
<h1>Books</h1>

{% block js %}
{{ block.super }}
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/337923491/endless.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/151379951/endless-pagination.js"></script>
<script>$.endlessPaginate();</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="endless_page_template">
{% include page_template %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

</body></html>
```

My latest_books_page.html :

```
<h2>Viewing All Entries</h2>

{% load endless %}
<div>
<ul>
{% paginate book_list %}
{% for book in book_list %}
<li>{{ book.name }}</li> {{ book.pub_date }}
{% endfor %}
{% show_pages %}
</ul>
</div>
```

I am facing two issues first if i use `{{ block.super }}` as given in [tutorial](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html) .Django gives this error `'BlockNode' object has no attribute 'context'` and if i remove `{{ block.super }}`. I get simple pagination with next and previous functionality .

Can someone help me please. I want to implement on scroll load pagination...

Comment: my JavaScript console shows this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try out my code:

views.py :

```
from models import Book
from django.template import RequestContext 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


def latest_books(request,template = 'latest_books.html',
                  page_template = 'latest_books_page.html' ):

    context = {}    
    book_list = Book.objects.order_by('-pub_date')

    context.update( {'book_list': book_list, 'page_template': page_template,} )

    # override the template and use the 'page' style instead.
    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template

    return render_to_response(
        template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

latest_books.html :

```
<html><head><title>Books</title></head>

<body>

<h1>Books</h1>
<h2>Viewing All Entries</h2>

<div class="endless_page_template">
    {% include page_template %}
</div>

{% block js %}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/endless_on_scroll.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/endless-pagination.js"></script>    
<script>
    $.endlessPaginate({paginateOnScroll: true,
    endless_on_scroll_margin : 10,
    paginateOnScrollChunkSize: 5        
});</script>
{% endblock %}


</body></html>
```

latest_books_page.html :

```
{% load endless %}
{% paginate 10 book_list %}
{% for book in book_list %}
{{ book.name }}<br> {{ book.pub_date }}<br><br><br>
{% endfor %}
{% show_more "even more" "working" %}
```

Try out and let me know ... and enter 20-30 entries into your DB to check it out properly ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `page_template` before call the `{{block.super}}`

```
<h2>Entries:</h2>
{% include page_template %}

{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
    <script>$.endlessPaginate();</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did that too but still getting `'BlockNode' object has no attribute 'context'` error

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566347/django-templates-using-block-super-in-included-template-fails-exception