# Django-endless-pagination twitter style pagination not working

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates, django-endless-pagination

I am using [django-endless-pagination](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for my project. But its not working as it is supposed to. Neither is it showing the `show more` or neither does it work when I change the code to `onscroll` mode.

```
<script>$.endlessPaginate({paginateOnScroll: true});</script>
```

However the include tags are working as its showing the snaps in the template. And even both the scripts (i.e. the jquery and endless.js) are there. What am I missing? Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

models.py:

```
class SnapGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)

class Snap(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(SnapGroup)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
@page_template('snapgroups.html')  # just add this decorator
def snaps(
        request, template='snaps.html', extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'snapgroup': SnapGroup.objects.all(),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return render_to_response(
        template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

snaps.html:

```
    {% if snapgroup.count > 0 %}

        <div class="endless_page_template">
            {% include page_template %}
        </div>


        {% block js %}
            {{ block.super }}
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
            <script>$.endlessPaginate();</script>
        {% endblock %}            

    {% else %}
        <li><p>No SNAPGROUP yet!</p></li>
        <span class="clear_both"></span>
    {% endif %}
```

snapgroups.html:

```
{% load endless %}

{% paginate snapgroup %}
{% for sg in snapgroup %}
    <h4 id="combination" class="snap_date">{{sg.date|date:'l'}}, {{sg.date}}</h4>
    <ul>
    {% for snap in sg.snap_set.all %}
        <li><a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{snap.image}}" data-imagelightbox="f"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{snap.image}}" alt="{{snap.caption}}" /></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
        <span class="clear_both"></span>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}

{% show_more %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540399/how-to-implement-end-less-pagination-in-django). Hope this will help someone else.